# I want to bypass the headers and have just the sum of the amount column, how do I do that?

Tags: python, sum, multiple-columns

This is what my data looks like:

```
'''
Symbol         Amount <br />
BB                1000 <br />
TIS            8574 <br />
LIG            1333 <br />
etc...          etc... <br />
etc...
'''
```

Since the first column is strings and the second is integers, how do I get the code to skip over the first column and only add the second?

This is what I have:

```
def total_shares(port_list):  
    column_sum = 0
    for x in port_list:
        column_sum = sum(x[1]) 
    return column_sum
```

port_list contains a list of tuples. I took that list and made it into two columns, now I was to add everything in the amount column only.

my existing code gives me this error -

```
column_sum = sum(x[1]) TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

**the def total_shares(port_list): is apart of the code but it won't show as it, I'm not sure why**

Comment: What is `port_list`? A string? A nested list? Something else? Also what is wrong with your existing code?

Comment: port_list contains a list of tuples. 
I took that list and made it into two columns 
now I was to add everything in the amount column only

Comment: my existing code gives me this error - column_sum = sum(x[1]) TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must change that line to

```
column_sum += x[1]
```

You can also use a one-liner alternative if you want to use the `sum()` function:

```
def total_shares(port_list):
    return sum(port[1] for port in port_list)
```